# How does HTML5 Video works

Tags: html, plugins, html5-video, media

I would like to know How a HTML5 compliant browser plays a video using tags.
Does it actually call the underlying Player APIs using some plugin API ? 
Can we write a custom plugin in chrome browser , such that using this we could call the Video player API like ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does it actually call the underlying Player APIs using some plugin API ?**

Yes, The video players are implementations written in the browser, but the only API exposed is that stated in the HTML standard (and those which exist in JS).

**Can we write a custom plugin in chrome browser?**

No.

**such that using this we could call the Video player API like ffmpeg ?**

No, and the issue of distributing codecs and licensing come into play here. All of the format support provided in modern HTML5 browsers have been given licensing access to decode formats such as MP4 and AAC.